# ExpressJS 4.x: simply render index.html with variables (like in Django)

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

Very **simple** question I can't find answer for.

Using ExpressJS 4.x I would like to do:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {name:"Peter"});
});
```

And then my index.html I want it to be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to write **plain HTML** (no pseudo html like pug, ejs, etc.), just plain html with the addition of variables this way: {{ variable }}

**Is this possible??** It must be easy...

Thank you very much for you help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html .

Basically uses a regex to match {{ .* }} with a replacer function to convert the {{}} to the value in view data.

```js
var fs = require('fs'); // this engine requires the fs module
app.engine('html', function (filePath, options, callback) { // define the template engine
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
    
    var rendered = content.toString().replace(/{{([^}]+)}}/g, function(match, p1) {
      return options[p1.trim()];
    });

    return callback(null, rendered);
  });
});
app.set('views', './views'); // specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'html'); // register the template engine
```

Comment: It worked :) Well, after changing content.replace to content.toString().replace.

Comment: I would like to use FOR and IF as well. Is there any minimalist render engine?

Comment: oh yes, missed that, edited and added back .toString() for future references

Comment: I had used [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), pretty rudimentary but quite extensible. It has for and if and very few functions built-in, but its extensibility is quite good.